# Is there anyway to set up RDP with OTP on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, rdp, one-time-password

As title described.
I just want to use RDP with more security.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Protectimus solution for RDP & WinLogon. It can be used both for corporate and personal Windows accounts and can be easily integrated. You can use hardware or software tokens, SMS and other methods to get OTPs.

Disclosure: I work for Protectimus Solutions.